# How to create different columns like int or string programmatically in parse data browser

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am a newbie to parse and I just started my parse programs and I wonder when I save data like parseobject.add("xyz","abc") the abc gets stored as an array but I want that to be stored as an string, similarly how can I store other types like int,boolean.

Comment: what is the type of parseObject actually? Can you post your code?

Comment: ParseObject person1 = new ParseObject("person4");
person1.add("age",22);
person1.saveInBackground();
The age is getting saved in my data browser but not as an integer but as an array format, so my doubt is how can I save it in a integer format rather than array.

Comment: Please refer the docs here https://parse.com/docs/android_guide
The implementation seems to store the key value pair. You can store and retrieve any key and value pair here.

Comment: I read the documentation but my doubt is
if you create the class in parse dashboard you can create the columns like int, string, boolean, file, array and you can select one of the type for your column.
But what if I create a column using object.add(KEY VALUE PAIR) and I want the column type to be an int or boolean, it is storing the key value pairs in array format even if I enter a number or string

Comment: From docs,

Data Types

So far we've used values with type String, int, bool, and ParseObject. Parse also supports java.util.Date, byte[], and JSONObject.NULL.

You can nest JSONObject and JSONArray objects to store more structured data within a single ParseObject.

Comment: You didn't get my doubt. My doubt is using data browser I can create columns for formats int,string,boolean  but if want to add a coulmn programatically only for type say int how to achieve it.
Also storing in JSON format complicates my scenario so I just need to create coulmn of type say int programatically..?? 
I hope you understood my problem...

Comment: You can restrict that by yourself before adding data into the parseObject by checking the type of the variables. You can use TypeToken to get the type of the variables. Am I getting your point?

Comment: Yes you got my point but what is typetoken and how to do it?

Comment: You can use my method I mentioned in my answer. You can use TypeToken, but for that you need gson. And TypeToken will not be work for primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
public boolean isNum(Object obj){
    return obj.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class);
 }
```

like this you can write methods to check the types and filter the type you want.

```
if(isNum(a))
{
  parseObject.add("a",a);
}
```

Comment: Hey I got answer for my question 
Doubt: How can we create columns like number and boolean programatically
Answer: When using put() in parse it first checks if it is available in the class if its not available it create one column..

Comment: Can you give some example.

Comment: ParseObject person = new ParseObject("persons");
person.put("age", 22);
person.saveInBackground();

In this above code if there is no column "age" for the class then it creates one class with number field, if it exists it will append the data to the existing column